# How to copy elements from one map to another in velocity

Tags: spring, velocity

Don't know is it possible to copy elements from one map to another map in velocity?This copies only last element

```
                #foreach($key in $departamentsMap.keySet())
                    $key - $departamentsMap.get($key)
                    #set($maap={$key:$departamentsMap.get($key)} )
                #end
```

Comment: Don't. Velocity is a view technology. Copy the values in the Controller, not the View

Comment: Thanks Patrick, now i know it

Comment: Why does everybody call me Patrick? The name's Sean :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're creating a new $maap every time.  Just do:

```
#set( $map = {} )
#set( $ignore = $map.putAll($departamentsMap) )
```

It's just a HashMap underneath.  Not complicated. :)